# Mauritian staying in France marrying Indonesian

Tags: visa, immigration, france

I am a Mauritian staying in France and shall marry an indonesian. I am in France on the title "Scientifique-Chercheur". I would like to know the procedures. Right now, the indonesian is doing the procedures in Indonesia and I will go there, we are going to marry and then we will get the Certificate on marriage. Also, my visa expires every year, this year, it is going to expire in September. From here, can I get some help how to proceed. Secondly, it is better that I make her procedures to go to Mauritius then from there come to France or it's better that she comes from Indonesia to France directly.